# Does \alloc@ change \allocationnumber globally?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I'm reading through plain.tex. This is the definition of `\alloc@`:

```
\def\alloc@#1#2#3#4#5{\global\advance\count1#1 by 1
\ch@ck#1#4#2% make sure there’s still room
\allocationnumber=\count1#1
\global#3#5=\allocationnumber
\wlog{\string#5=\string#2\the\allocationnumber}}
```

I understand how this works, except the line which sets `\allocationnumber`. The TeXbook says that you can check `\allocationnumber` (which is `\count21`) after the call, to see what number was allocated. How can this be, if the assignment to `\allocationnumber` isn't marked `\global`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the text states you can check `\allocationnumber` after the call and
it implies that you do it more or less immediately after the call. The
cited code snippet demonstrates this with its last line: The
`\allocationnumber` is written via `\wlog` to the log file.

And yes the information is lost if between the call of `\alloc@` and the
check of `\allocationnumber` a group ends as `\allocationnumber` is
restored to the value that it had at the start of the group. With
`\global` the `\allocationnumber` would survive.

But what do you do after `\newcount\mycnt \newdimen\mydim` if you need
the `\allocationnumber` of `\mycnt`? It's gone as `\allocationnumber` stores now the number of `\mydim`. It's a completely unrelated number from a different count register (`\count11` vs `\count10`). Thus, a `\global` doesn't help much; retrieve the number directly after you used `\alloc@` or a command that calls it.